# node hrTime as increment id

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, time

Node has `process.hrtime` as per:

- [process.hrtime()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time)
- [process.hrtime.bigint()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_bigint)

Suppose there is an append only event stream that should be persisted (either in database or file).

- How bad or good is idea to use `node`'s `hrtime` as incremental ID for ordering purposes?
- Is it safe to assume that since `node` is like single threaded event loop, that there won't be collisions or out-of-order timestamps in the scope of single process?
- How about to use it across multiple hosts generating events for that event stream, assuming that all clocks are NTP synchronized what is the probability to get out-of-order events from different hosts?
- What is the collision probability across multiple hosts assuming that all clocks NTP synchronized?
- Since it will depend much on throughput of system, at what point problems will arise? 100, 1,000, 10,000, 100,000 events/sec?

Any open source project that uses `hrtime` for such purpose to refer?

For instance, system might not be running under very high throughput, but one action may cause multiple events, considering high performance CPUs, it is very high probability that calling `new Date().getTime()` multiple times in the scope of processing that action, will cause same millisecond-resolution timestamps to be generated.

Comment: No, there is no guarantee that you're not getting duplicates from subsequent calls. Also, "*These times are relative to an arbitrary time in the past*" so no you cannot use them on multiple hosts and NTP synchronisation does not affect them at all.

Comment: 1) NTP synchronization does not affect them, because `libuv` implements `hrTime` as `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...)` which is clear now.
2) since it is `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, in the scope of single process it should be safe to assume lack of collisions and strict in order.
3) for multi-process / multi-host of course there might/will be collisions, the question is how bad

Comment: Basically it drills down to:
- `node` [node_process_methods.cc](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/efc39464b0d813f15188d2d9cf14b74bcca61750/src/node_process_methods.cc#L147)
- `libuv` [posix-hrtime](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/dabc737d7892971289537e52af4366c63cbc70b3/src/unix/posix-hrtime.c#L31)
- [man clock_getres (2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)

Comment: I couldn't find out whether CLOCK_MONOTONIC means "strictly increasing" or just "non-decreasing".

Comment: For instance [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/posix-clocks.html) and many other places. It is monotonically increasing time while CPU ticks. Its absolute value meaningless. Also assuming that `node` event loop is kinda single threaded, it definitely should result in increasing results.

Comment: Ah, thanks: "*its timestamps are guaranteed to be unique and monotonically increasing*" is clear.

Comment: You now might want to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, on Linux, `node`'s `hrtime` drills down to:

- `node` [`node_process_methods.cc`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/efc39464b0d813f15188d2d9cf14b74bcca61750/src/node_process_methods.cc#L147)
- `libuv` [`posix-hrtime.c`](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/dabc737d7892971289537e52af4366c63cbc70b3/src/unix/posix-hrtime.c#L31)
- [`man CLOCK_GETRES (2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)

`libuv` uses `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...)` to provide `hrtime`. Many answers on SO can be found by looking for `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

As per manual:

> CLOCK_MONOTONIC
>   Clock that cannot be set and represents monotonic time since — as described by POSIX—"some unspecified point in the past". On Linux, that point corresponds to the number of seconds that the system has been running since it was booted.
>   The CLOCK_MONOTONIC clock is not affected by discontinuous jumps in the system time (e.g., if the system administrator manually changes the clock), but is affected by the incremental adjustments performed by adjtime(3) and NTP. This clock does not count time that the system is suspended.

As result `hrtime` is not affected by NTP jumps. But it cannot be used as absolute time as well due to the same reasons. `hrtime` only meaningful to calculate time between executions.

However, assuming that `node` is kinda single threaded, and definition of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is always incremented (for instance [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/posix-clocks.html)), subsequent calls to `hrtime` should provide results in incremented manner, regardless of throughput.

For the same reasons that `node` is kinda single threaded, the following simple function could workaround same millisecond-resolution times (as illustration):

```
let myLastTime = 0;
function getMyTime() {
  const newTime = new Date().getTime();
  if (newTime > myLastTime) {
    myLastTime = newTime;
    return myLastTime;
  }
  if (newTime === myLastTime) {
    myLastTime = newTime + 1;
    returm myLastTime;
  }
  // bad case if NTP jump for instance
  // and we need always increment time
  if (newTime < myLastTime) {
    myLastTime = myLastTime + 1;
    return myLastTime;
  }
}
```

Solution illustrated above won't do well under high throughput. There are only 1000 milliseconds in a second, thus theoretically having throughput of 1000 or more events in a second, most likely will move `myLastTime` clock into the future, causing more problems than it solves. But might be good for throughput quite under 1000 events with single writer (i.e. not distributed multi-host scenario).

In distributed multi-host environment, time is bad reference for order in any case. Because each host's clocks may behave differently, also there will be NTP jumps impact etc.

Conclusion, to guarantee persisted order, either application should rely on underlying storage that guarantees it, or application should manage the order via logical sequence number or alike.